# What is meant by ' !! ' and how to use it with object, string or array

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a method as follows. what is mean by `!!` and what is happening here?

```
private isDxsLoaded(): boolean {
    return !!this.dx;
}
```

Comment: Use a couple of NOT operators in series to explicitly force the conversion of any value to the corresponding [boolean primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). The conversion is based on the "truthyness" or "falsyness" of the value (see [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/falsy).See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Logical Operators - Double NOT (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript you can have *true* and *false* statements, like known in most other languages but you can also have *truthy* and *falsy*.

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when
>   encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they
>   are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined,
>   and NaN).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

The ! operator is not. So

```
 return !false // will return true
 return !!false // will return false
```

So when we put that together:

this.dx propably holds some value, a text, an object or an array.

```
this.dx = 'mytext'
```

So the statement

```
if (this.dx) { } // is truthy because it contains strings

if (!this.dx) { } // is falsy

if (!!this.dx) {} // true
```

The function

```
private isDxsLoaded(): boolean {
    return !!this.dx;
}
```

Is supposed to return true or false, so instead of doing something like

```
private isDxsLoaded(): boolean {
  if (this.dx && this.dx.length > 0) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
}
```

They are utalizing truthy/falsy statements with double not operator

```
return this.dx // would return a string or an object (i don't know what this.dx is)
return !this.dx // will return false
return !!this.dx // will return true
```

Basically the code is saying: If this.dx contains some value (string, objects, array, numbers (other than 0), then return true.